# Implicit return value scope in Ruby

Tags: ruby, return-type, implicit-declaration

I'm using a self-defined `include?` method to examine the difference between explicit and implicit returns. I understand that `#each` returns the collection iterated on, so I believe that I need to place my true/false implicit returns in the correct place, but when I do I am getting back the collection and I'm not sure what to modify.

```
def self.include?(array, search_item)
  array.each do |elem|
    if elem == search_item
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Below are the tests I'm checking, but I'm not understanding how to match the returns correctly. Why are they not matching or how should I understand the scope of the implicit return?

```
  result = MethodReturns.include?(numbers_array, 4)
  expect(result).to eq(true)

  result = MethodReturns.include?(numbers_array, 7)
  expect(result).to eq(false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to change to:

```
def self.include?(array, search_item)
  array.each do |elem|
    if elem == search_item
      return true
    end
  end
  return false
end
```

The reason for this is because the last statement in the method is the return value. In your case you never return false if there is no match. Be sure to add the `return` when you want to break out and stop the rest of the method execution immediately.

Comment: Your code is correct but your explanation is not. The `return` _inside_ the loop is crucial as otherwise the `true` would be swallowed up by `each` and never be returned.

Comment: I always write return when needing to basically break out of the executing method so I never think of that. Thanks for the add.

Comment: @Max For further clarification: the value returned by a block is the last expression to execute in a block. The `each` method takes in a block, and in this case, the block does return true if the current element is the search item and false otherwise. This issue is, however, and the `each` method ignores the output from each execution of the block and is instead defined to return the array that the each method was called on. So, since the `each` method call was the last expression in the method, the array is returned by this implementation of include?

Answer (score 3):

The LAST statement executed provides the return value.  The last thing that happens in an each() loop will always be the ending of the loop(unless you break out of the loop somehow, e.g. return, break):

```
def do_stuff()
  [1, 2, 3]. each do |num|
    true if num == num
  end
end

p do_stuff

--output:--
[1, 2, 3]
```

So your true value gets thrown away, and then the iteration with each() continues until the each() loop ends, and as you know, when an each() loop ends it returns the left hand side.

Here's an example of a method that implicitly returns true:

```
def do_stuff()
  [1, 2, 3]. each do |num|
    #blah
  end

  true
end
```

The each() method still returns the array--but the each() method is not the LAST statement that executes in the do_stuff() method.

In your example, you *could* do this:

```
def do_stuff(target)
  found = false

  [1, 2, 3]. each do |num|
    found = true if num == target
  end

  found
end


p do_stuff(2)

--output:--
true
```

However, that solution wastes resources because the each() method continues iterating over the Array after a match is found.  For instance, if your Array had 1 million elements in it, and a match was found at index 0 in the Array, the each() method would needlessly continue iterating over the remaining 999,999 elements. On the other hand, returning explicitly when a match is found will terminate the loop.

It is never a mistake to explicitly write `return val`.  As you get more experienced, you can drop the return portion--WHEN APPROPRIATE--to show the world you know ruby...however every now and then omitting `return` will still trip you up.

Answer (score 2):

If you use explicit `return` inside your `each` block - reaching that code will result in immediately returning the value (stopping the iteration). This is because of the [non local return](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/07/the-building-blocks-of-ruby/) feature of blocks:

> Ruby’s blocks support non-local-return, which means that a return from
>   the block behaves identically to returning from the block’s original
>   context.

So your code should work properly if you simply use explicit `return`:

```
def self.include?(array, search_item)
  array.each do |elem|
    if elem == search_item
      return true
    end
  end
end
```